# Symfony 5 Stripe Webhook redirection 307

Tags: symfony, stripe-payments, webhooks

This message is addressed to Symfony specialists who have already implemented Stripe in their project.

I have integrated Stripe in my Symfony project; it is a project where the user can subscribe to various formulas.

My payments are fine, however I have a problem with my webhook:

When I listen to events with my stripe cli, it lists many events but with a 307 redirection each time.

I asked for help from support, I tested several things, like starting from a blank project following the Stripe developers tutorials, checking my .htaccess file, but to no avail.

And then I tested starting from a project from scratch (not Symfony): Ta-Dam! I have my code 200 !

So here's my question: where in Symfony could it block to answer me a 307 code?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean that when you are forwarding the events received with `stripe listen --forward-to` that your internal server is responding with a 307?

Comment: How are you defining your routes for the webhook handler? The symfony docs suggest that 307 corresponds to a temporary redirect which preserved the request method: https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#redirecting-to-urls-and-routes-directly-from-a-route

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact same problem today, and it appears that i was forwarding the requests to an http:// URL while my symfony dev server was running on https://
Symfony was redirecting those http requests to https, thus the 307.

So the fix was simply to change to *http* to *https* in :

```
stripe listen --forward-to https://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you have configured your server and webhook endpoint, this could be because of a trailing slash.

Let's say you have defined your webhook endpoint at `http://localhost:8000/webhook`, make sure to run `stripe listen --forward-to http://localhost:8000/webhook` and not `stripe listen --forward-to http://localhost:8000/webhook/`

If you do the latter it will result in a 307, but again, this mostly depends on your server setup.